# Viewing & editing data in Google Sheets using a form

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to view and edit data in Google Sheets in a form, like MS Access or OpenOffice Base can do that? It would be perfect if we could cycle through each record, which would be the respective row in Spreadsheets.

The background is that we're storing personnel-type records in Sheets. We'd like to see (and edit) all the fields in a record in one screen, instead of stretched across multiple screens. The "Forms" program seems to be solely intended for collecting information, like a questionnaire, which isn't what we want. Ideally, we'd have some formatting controls so that "first name" could be placed right up against "last name", for example.

Does anyone know of an Add-on, etc, which can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets hasn't data forms like MS Access or OpenOffice Base. It either has something similar to 
[Excel's data form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-edit-find-and-delete-rows-by-using-a-data-form-17bca0a4-3ba5-444a-983c-a8ce70609374) , but it's possible to link a Google Form to new Google Sheets' sheet and with a bit of work (by using Google Apps Script) it's possible to include a link to edit the form responses using Google Form which will update the data on the sheet.

Linking a spreadsheet to a form could be done from Google Sheets. This will create a new form. Also this could be done from Google Forms but you could create a new spreadsheet or use an existing spreadsheet.

It's worth to note that the Form has it's own data repository. When a response is submitted a copy of the form data response is copied to the linked sheet. Changes made directly on the sheet will not automatically be sent to the form data repository.

Also it's possible to use Google Apps Script to create a form and to submit data to the form.

NOTE: Some time ago I published an add-on that shows a row data on a side panel, it's called [Visor de Registros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visor-de-registros/ogebefhoajbmkidcfakdphehlcopnboo?utm_source=permalink) (record viewer).

Related

- [In Google Sheets: How do I merge a range of a row (the header) with the range of each column into a single cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119549/88163)
- [Display the name of a cell in a worksheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119316/88163)

Answer (score 0):

I found a very partial solution.
I created a second sheet and used the `TRANSPOSE` function to swap the row into a column. Then I copied and pasted that info, one by one, into a document. That gave me a hand-compiled report. Tedious, but at least it was usable.

But I'm still looking for a way of interactively editing Sheets info in a "form" format.

Comment: This looks more as a progress update than an answer.